# springjdbctemplate no value specified at parameter 2

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

Please help me fix the following error.When I am trying to add new entry in spring mvc with jdbctemplate,it is showing an error.But when I go back to the main page I can see the new entry added.

**HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into person( id, first_name, last_name, Money) values (?,?,?,?) ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2**

Code for adding entry is.

```
             public void add(Person person) {
    logger.debug("Adding new person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement using Named Parameters style
    String query = "insert into person( id, first_name, last_name, Money) values (?,?,?,?) ";

    //simpleJdbcTemplate.update(query,  person.getId(), person.getFirstName(),person.getLastName(), person.getMoney());
            //"(:firstName, :lastName, :money)";

    // Assign values to parameters
    //Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //parameters.put("first_name", firstName);
    //parameters.put("last_name", lastName);
    //parameters.put("Money", money);

    // Save

    jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] { String.valueOf(person.getId()),
            person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName(),person.getMoney() });




    jdbcTemplate.update(query, person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amzi

It could be an Issue with the primary Key. How did you define the Primary key in the table is it an Auto generated key ?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

Did you try to use a preparedStatement.
jdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator psc)
or

jdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator psc, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder)
---Issue an update statement using a PreparedStatementCreator to provide SQL and any required parameters.

Is Money an object you application ?
Looks like its not able to find it.

Comment: Primary key is auto generated in table and Money is object in my code and it is being saved in database.Please view the full code http://stackoverflow.com/q/17708465/1403843

Answer (score 0):

Could you modify your code to the following?

The program maybe execute successfuly.

here is modified code

```
Object[] args = new Object[] { String.valueOf(person.getId()),
            person.getFirstName(), 
person.getLastName(),person.getMoney()};
jdbcTemplate.update(query, args);
```

//////////////////////////////////

By the way, I have taken the same misstake...

regards.

wb_fox